# Can I use a Custom method in a WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have these two models in my Rails application:

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.float    "latitude",   limit: 24,    default: 0.0
  t.float    "longitude",  limit: 24,    default: 0.0
```

User:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.float    "last_latitude",         limit: 24,    default: 0.0
  t.float    "last_longitude",        limit: 24,    default: 0.0111
```

And I have a Custom Class:

```
class CalculusAid
  public
    # point_one and point_two are arrays of [latitude, longitude]

    def self.distance point_one, point_two

    first_point_latitude,  first_point_longitude  = point_one
    second_point_latitude, second_point_longitude = point_two

    latitude_difference_in_radians = (first_point_latitude - second_point_latitude).to_radians
    longitude_difference_in_radians = (first_point_longitude - second_point_longitude).to_radians

    #Math stuff
    a = Math.sin(latitude_difference_in_radians/2) * Math.sin(latitude_difference_in_radians/2) +
    Math.cos(first_point_latitude.to_radians) * Math.cos(second_point_latitude.to_radians) *
    Math.sin(longitude_difference_in_radians/2) * Math.sin(longitude_difference_in_radians/2);
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

    distance_in_kilometers = 6371 * c; # Multiply by 6371 to get Kilometers
    return distance_in_kilometers
 end
 ...
```

What I wan't to do is return 5 random projects that are between 0 and 50kilometers from the user, to do it i thought in a method like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_nearby_projects
     @nearby_projects = User.joins(:projects).where(CalculusAid.distance([self.last_longitude],self.last_latitude][project.longitude,project.latitude]) < 50).limit(5).order("RAND()")
  end
```

But I don't know if I can use a custom method in a where statement or if the syntax is right.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible directly, since Rails just builds a query to be executed by MySQL, and gets a result from DB server. It is an atomic operation and one can not pass a lambda to MySQL to filter results.

But MySQL has [built-in math functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html):

```
@nearby_projects = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
  SELECT * 
  FROM users
    JOIN projects ON (???) -- unclear from the code you’ve pasted
  WHERE
    50 > 6371 * (SIN(users.last_latitude + .......
SQL
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can't i replace the 50 > 6371 *(SIN... with the distance function?

Comment: No, you should rewrite it in pure SQL.

Comment: Ok, if there isn't a better way i will do it

Comment: Not the one I am aware of. Maybe future visitors will suggest something better.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you a simple "where range < 50km".
Additionally you can make a call to random in the Order statement?

```
SELECT a,b,c, ... 
FROM table
WHERE range < 50
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: I don't have a range method